# I don't get it (vba only works for half the columns)

Tags: excel, vba

I. Do. Not. Understand.

I am trying to delete rows based on a value (target located in column 11).
This code only works for half the cells i want to delete, so i have to run it like 10 times (it goes from 520, then to 260, then 130, 65...)

My code seems simple enough but i still cannot quite figure out where the issue is...

Thanks for your help

```
Dim Target As String, i As Integer
Target = "Réduction ligne"
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To lastrow
    On Error Resume Next
    If Cells(i, 11).Value = Target Then
    Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete = True
   End If
Next i
```

Comment: You should iterate backwards. Otherwise the reference is lost... A better/faster way will be to place all the cells from the rows to be deleted in a (Union) range and then delete its EntireRow at once.

Comment: Do a reverse looping `For i =  lastrow to 1 Step -1`

Comment: Also you do not need a loop to delete rows containing  "Réduction ligne". Use [AUTOFILTER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317172/delete-row-based-on-partial-text/11317372#11317372). It is much faster.

Comment: Has been answered very often at SO, e.g. at [...Delete entire row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767277/excel-vba-if-cell-is-an-integer-delete-the-entire-row/11767564#11767564)

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick reply, i'm new to vba so i still have trouble optimizing my macros

Answer (score 0):

**The most important thing first:**

```
On Error Resume Next
```

Please don't do that. It will make debugging your code a nightmare.

---

**Why does your problem happen:**

Now with this out of the way, let's look at the source of your problem. You have the following rows:

```
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 D
```

In your first loop iteration `i = 1`. Row `1` is deleted. Now your data looks like this:

```
1 B
2 C
3 D
```

In your second loop iteration `i = 2`. Since row 1 has been deleted, you are *actually* looking at the *third* original row.

---

**How do I fix this:**

This problem can be solved by iterating backwards:

```
For i = lastrow To 1 Step -1
```

Comment: It makes so much sense once you understand how the function works, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub efficientDeleteRows()
  Dim Target As String, lastRow As Long, i As Long, rngDel As Range
 Target = "Réduction ligne"
 lastRow = cells(rows.count, 11).End(xlUp).row
 For i = 1 To lastRow
    If cells(i, 11).value = Target Then
        If rngDel Is Nothing Then
            Set rngDel = cells(i, 11)
        Else
            Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, cells(i, 11))
        End If
    End If
 Next i
 If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: I will give that a shot, thanks